# Can I log in to different asp.net mvc4 areas, with different credentials, without the login session clashing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-areas, simplemembership

I have an asp.net mvc4 application, using simplemembership for the authentication.
In this application I have an admin area, and the frontend which is the root of the application (not an area).
I would like to be able to log in to both areas without overwriting the login session of the other.
Is it possible to define the admin area as a seperate application, and how?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the admin to be able to log into both the administive section of the site and the "regular" authenticated part of the site, but non-admin users to only be able to log into the "regular" authenticated part of the site?

Could you just use Roles to decorate the controller actions that are only available to Administrators vs those that are available to any authorized user?

[Authorize(Roles="Admininstrator")] for administrator-only actions

[Authorize] for any authorized user actions

http://geekswithblogs.net/tyarmer/archive/2010/02/25/strongly-typed-roles-in-mvc-with-authorize-attribute.aspx

Or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?